# Best practice using map to create a new record inside my database with Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap

I am using a third party API to collect data in a hash format. What I'm trying to do is take the hash data and store it into my database.

Say I have a hash instantiated called comments. Inside comments, the hash returns the following

```
{"message"=>"Welcome to New York", "from"=>{"name"=>"John Doe"}
```

I'd like to take this hash and store the message and from inside a table called Comment.

I was wondering what the best rails practice is here for accomplishing this.

Comment: How does your table's schema look like?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, you would simply create models (with corresponding database tables) for your data as you see fit. This depends on your domain, i.e., what you actually want to store, and what you want to achieve.

In your case, you would probably end up with two database tables:

- Table PERSON with columns ID, NAME, ...
- Table MESSAGE with columns ID, PERSON_ID, TEXT, ...

So, you can simply use the Rails generators to create all this stuff pretty simply. Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and the "guides index" on that page for more information, these should all be explained in detail in the first basic chapters.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Comment model and use ActiveRecord to store it in your database.
Under the folder app/model/ create a file model.rb
inside write something like

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
end
```

You will need to configure rails to enable communication with database,
and a few more things.
You can find documentation on ActiveRecord [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

Once everything is set up you could write something like that in your controller :

```
my_hash = {"message"=>"Welcome to New York", "from"=>{"name"=>"John Doe"}
message = message.new(my_hash['message'])
message.save
```

Comment: I would be happy to improve my answer if you could explain why you downvoted it :-)